# Десериализация массива

Tags: c#

Как десериализовать такой json ?

```
[
    {
        "age": 36,
        "name": "Антон"
    },
    {
        "age": 25,
        "name": "Вася"
    }
]
```

Есть класс

```
public class PersonList
{
    public Person[] Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [JsonPropertyName("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Пробую так, но получаю ошибку `System.Text.Json.JsonException`

```
PersonList personList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonList>(stringJson);
```

Comment: Перемудрили. `Person[] persons = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person[]>(stringJson);`, класс `PersonList` не нужен.

Comment: @aepot понял, спасибо!